# Detect and save multiples position using Position() of RStudio

Tags: r

I would like to use the function Position() (RStudio) to identify multiples position with NULL of a list and generate a vector with these position values

I have a list with NULL in some position.

> `list1`

[[1]]
[1] 0.58

[[2]]
[1] NULL

[[3]]
[1] 0.65

[[4]]
[1] NULL

By using the function Position() I can identify the position of the NULL, but I just identify one:

> 

```
positionA <- Position(is.null, list1)
positionA
```

[1] 2

I would like to identify every NULL and I tried with a for but it generated values of 1 instead the real position (2 and 4 of the list1)

```
vector1 <- vector("integer", length = 4)
```

> 

```
for (i in 1:4) 
  {
    vector1[i] = Position(is.null, list1[i])
  }
  vector1
```

[1] NA 1 NA 1

I would like to get a position like this

> `vector1`

[1]  2  4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to use the function Position(), it seems it works with vectors not list, how about `which(unlist(lapply(list1, function(x) is.null(x))))`